# mod_rewrite to make clean URL with multiple patterns

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm trying to make clean URLs for my application. So I wrote the codes below in a **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

As you can see, I may have at most 2 variable in query string; **p** and **id**. If I have just one rule (the rule with 1 variable) in .htaccess file, everything will be fine. But when I add the first rule (the rule with 2 variable), it seems that all css, js, and image files will be go away.
I wrote css, images, and js files in this way :

> ./directory_name/file_name

Please help me to make clean URLs with multiple rules.

Comment: Check your CSS/JS links. The `RewriteCond`s should cause those not to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I'm running the application locally, and after applying your codes, no page does not show

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, just fixed it. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following a [Front-Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), (i.e. everything goes through `index.php`) I'd encourage you to use [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

It's more concise and performant than the `mod_rewrite` equivalent (as seen in **anubhava's** answer):